# Decide the line through two points

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this problem below that i don't understand:

> Let $L_1$ be a straight line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as defined by $(x, y, z) = (2,2,0) + t(3,0,2)$.

> a) Determine the plane that contains the line $L_1$ and the point $A = (8, 2, 3)$.

And i solved a with taking the point in the line $L_1$ with $(8,2,3)-(2,2,0) = (6,0,3)$.
And after that i did the Cross-product on the vector $(3,0,2) \times (6,0,3)$ and i got the
vector that is ortogonal on these two vectors $(0,3,0)$.

And after that i put in the point $(2,2,0)$ in the plane equation and got that the plane is
$y=2$.

But then i came to the b) part that troubled me below:

> b) The line $L_2$ is defined by $(x, y, z) = (5, 1, 0) + t (2, 1, 1)$. Determine an equation for that line which passes through the point $A = (8, 2, 3)$ and intersects both $L_1$ and $L_2$.

I don't know what to begin to right here they say you should use the plane equation you
got in part a) with is $y=2$ but i'don't understand.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You may already realize this, but the wording you use for your attempts at mathematical writing sometimes makes it look like you're wrong even when you do the math correctly. Trying to parse "with taking the point in the line $L_1$ with $(8,2,3)-(2,2,0) = (6,0,3)$," initially I thought you meant that $(6,0,3)$ is a point in $L_1$ (which is false). It is a fact that $(6,0,3)$ is the displacement vector from a point on $L_1$ (specifically the point $(2,2,0)$) to the point $A,$ which may be what you meant to do but wasn't what you said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line you are looking for passes through $A$ and it intersects $L_1$. Therefore it is along the plane $y=2$, which contains $A$ and  any point in the line $L_1$. It follows that such line should pass through the point $B$ given by the intersection of $y=2$ and $L_2$:
$$(x, 2, z) = (5, 1, 0) + t (2, 1, 1) \implies t=1, \quad
B=(5, 1, 0) + 1 (2, 1, 1)=(7,2,1).$$

So this line goes through $A=(8,2,3)$ and $B=(7,2,1)$. Can you finish the job?

Comment: Okay sorry i know should discuss here but i have one question is that the y value should equal 2 like in the vector (7,2,1) because we have a 2 in the middle? @Robert Z

Comment: @john See my edit. It is clear now?

Comment: Okay @Robert Z Thanks last question is (7,2,1) a vector or a point?

Comment: @john It represents the intersection point $B$. BTW read carefully the comment of David K above.

Comment: Thanks so much :) !

Comment: Nice (+1), but I failed to understand the “(in a different point)” part of your answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You are right, that part is useless.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Robert Z is fine and I cannot improve it, but I will provide my answer nevertheless, since it is about how to solve part b) without using part a) of the problem.

An arbitrary point of $L_1$ has the form $(2,2,0)+t(3,0,2)$. The line defined by $A$ and that point is the line$$\left\{(8,2,3)+u\bigl((2,2,0)+t(3,0,2)-(8,2,3)\bigr)\,\middle|\,u\in\Bbb R\right\}$$which is equal to$$\left\{(8,2,3)+u\bigl((-6,0,-3)+t(3,0,2)\bigr)\,\middle|\,u\in\Bbb R\right\}.$$A point of this line belongs to $L_2$ if it is of the form $(5,1,0)+v(2,1,1)$, for some $v\in\Bbb R$. So, you want to know when is it that we have$$(8,2,3)+u\bigl((-6,0,-3)+t(3,0,2)\bigr)=(5,1,0)+v(2,1,1).$$In other words, when do we have$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}3 t u-6 u-2 v+3=0\\1-v=0\\2 t u-3 u-v+3=0?\end{array}\right.$$It follows from the second equation that $v=1$ and then $(5,1,0)+v(2,1,1)=(7,2,1)$. So, the line that you're after is the line defined by $A$ and $(7,2,1)$.